# JS-style async/non-blocking callback execution with Ruby, without heavy machinery like threads?

Tags: ruby

I'm a frontend developer, somewhat familiar with Ruby. I only know how to do Ruby in a synchronous/sequential manner, while in JS i'm used to async/non-blocking callbacks.

Here's sample Ruby code:

```
results = []
rounds = 5

callback = ->(item) {
  # This imitates that the callback may take time to complete
  sleep rand(1..5)

  results.push item

  if results.size == rounds
    puts "All #{rounds} requests have completed! Here they are:", *results
  end
}

1.upto(rounds) { |item| callback.call(item) }

puts "Hello"
```

The goal is to have the callbacks run without blocking main script execution. In other words, i want "Hello" line to appear in output above the "All 5 requests..." line. Also, the callbacks should run concurrently, so that the callback fastest to finish makes it into the resulting array first.

With JavaScript, i would simply wrap the callback call into a `setTimeout` with zero delay:

```
setTimeout( function() { callback(item); }, 0);
```

This JS approach does not implement true multithreading/concurrency/parallel execution. Under the hood, the callbacks would run all in one thread sequentially, or rather interlaced on the low level.

But on practical level it would appear as concurrent execution: the resulting array would be populated in an order corresponding to the amount of time spent by each callback, i. e. the resulting array would appear sorted by the time it took each callback to finish.

**Note that i only want the asynchronous feature of `setTimeout()`. I don't need the sleep feature built into `setTimeout()`** (not to be confused with a `sleep` used in the callback example to imitate a time-consuming operation).

I tried to inquire into how to do that JS-style async approach with Ruby and was given suggestions to use:

1. Multithreading. This is probably THE approach for Ruby, but it requires a substantial amount of scaffolding:

   1. Manually define an array for threads.
   2. Manually define a mutex.
   3. Start a new thread for each callback, add it to the array.
   4. Pass the mutex into each callback.
   5. Use mutex in the callback for thread synchronization.
   6. Ensure all threads are completed before program completion.

   Compared to JavaScript's `setTimeout()`, this is just too much. As i don't need true parallel execution, i don't want to build that much scaffolding every time i want to execute a proc asynchronously.
2. A sophisticated Ruby library like Celluloid and Event Machine. They look like it will take weeks to learn them.
3. A custom solution like [this one](https://gist.github.com/apeiros/500d3188a81f133f1df9) (the author, apeiros@freenode, claims it to be very close to what setTimeout does under the hood). It requires almost no scaffolding to build and it does not involve threads. But it seems to run callbacks synchronously, in the order they've been executed.

I have always considered Ruby to be a programming language most close to my ideal, and JS to be a poor man's programming language. And it kinda discourages me that Ruby is not able to do a thing which is trivial with JS, without involving heavy machinery.

So the question is: what is the simplest, most intuitive way to do do async/non-blocking callback with Ruby, without involving complicated machinery like threads or complex libraries?

PS If there will be no satisfying answer during the bounty period, i will dig into #3 by apeiros and probably make it the accepted answer.

Comment: You will need, at a minimum, either threads or an event loop. So I suppose the answer would be “there isn’t one”, but really, threads and event libraries aren’t too bad. What are you going to use this for, by the way? There’s no getting around the fact that `sleep` is synchronous. (Think for a moment about how you would implement `setTimeout` from scratch in JavaScript, even with easy access to events and thread-likes as with Node.js and web workers.)

Comment: `sleep` is only an imitation of some time-consuming job: calculating something, reading data from disk or doing a network request. I'm trying to figure out the basic approach rather than solving a specific task. In JS i use Ajax/setTimeout branching all the time. For me Ruby has been an etalon of a nearly ideal language, but due to the lack of such a simple branching mechanism i have started feeling uncomfortable using Ruby.

Comment: Sure, but the last part still applies. “Calculating something” doesn’t sound asynchronous, first off. An event loop doesn’t really help with that. As for I/O, keep in mind that whichever library you use to do it has to support asynchronicity in the first place.

Comment: This has nothing to do w/the languages and everything to do w/the fact that JS runs single-threadedly in the browser, and historically a need to not block the main thread was needed, so `setTimeout`.  Ruby doesn't execute in the browser, and its libraries historically didn't have this constraint, so the solution you're looking for won't be satisfied in the core Ruby language or libraries without some work.  Many (most?) languages will be this way.

Comment: @NickVeys, i understand that. My question is what way of branching out procs is the simpliest in Ruby. I don't want to overcomplicate it with mutexes, thread synchronization, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some fiddling with threads and studying contributions by apeiros and asQuirreL, i came up with a solution that suits me.

I'll show sample usage first, source code in the end.

## Example 1: simple non-blocking execution

First, a **JS** example that i'm trying to mimic:

```
setTimeout( function() {
  console.log("world");
}, 0);

console.log("hello");

// 'Will print "hello" first, then "world"'.
```

Here's how i can do it with my tiny **Ruby** library:

```
# You wrap all your code into this...
Branch.new do

  # ...and you gain access to the `branch` method that accepts a block.
  # This block runs non-blockingly, just like in JS `setTimeout(callback, 0)`.
  branch { puts "world!" }

  print "Hello, "

end

# Will print "Hello, world!"
```

Note how you don't have to take care of creating threads, waiting for them to finish. The only scaffolding required is the `Branch.new { ... }` wrapper.

## Example 2: synchronizing threads with a mutex

Now we'll assume that we're working with some input and output shared among threads.

**JS** code i'm trying to reproduce with Ruby:

```
var
  results = [],
  rounds = 5;

for (var i = 1; i <= rounds; i++) {

  console.log("Starting thread #" + i + ".");

  // "Creating local scope"
  (function(local_i) {
    setTimeout( function() {

      // "Assuming there's a time-consuming operation here."

      results.push(local_i);
      console.log("Thread #" + local_i + " has finished.");

      if (results.length === rounds)
        console.log("All " + rounds + " threads have completed! Bye!");

    }, 0);
  })(i);
}

console.log("All threads started!");
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Starting thread #1.
Starting thread #2.
Starting thread #3.
Starting thread #4.
Starting thread #5.
All threads started!
Thread #5 has finished.
Thread #4 has finished.
Thread #3 has finished.
Thread #2 has finished.
Thread #1 has finished.
All 5 threads have completed! Bye!
```

Notice that the callbacks finish in reverse order.

We're also gonna assume that working the `results` array may produce a race condition. In JS this is never an issue, but in multithreaded Ruby this has to be addressed with a mutex.

**Ruby** equivalent of the above:

```
Branch.new 1 do

  # Setting up an array to be filled with that many values.
  results = []
  rounds = 5

  # Running `branch` N times:
  1.upto(rounds) do |item|

    puts "Starting thread ##{item}."

    # The block passed to `branch` accepts a hash with mutexes 
    # that you can use to synchronize threads.
    branch do |mutexes|

      # This imitates that the callback may take time to complete.
      # Threads will finish in reverse order.
      sleep (6.0 - item) / 10

      # When you need a mutex, you simply request one from the hash.
      # For each unique key, a new mutex will be created lazily.
      mutexes[:array_and_output].synchronize do
        puts "Thread ##{item} has finished!"
        results.push item

        if results.size == rounds
          puts "All #{rounds} threads have completed! Bye!"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  puts "All threads started."
end

puts "All threads finished!"
```

Note how you don't have to take care of creating threads, waiting for them to finish, creating mutexes and passing them into the block.

## Example 3: delaying execution of the block

If you need the delay feature of `setTimeout`, you can do it like this.

**JS**:

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Foo'); }, 2000);
```

**Ruby**:

```
branch(2) { puts 'Foo' }
```

## Example 4: waiting for all threads to finish

With JS, there's no simple way to have the script wait for all threads to finish. You'll need an await/defer library for that.

But in Ruby it's possible, and Branch makes it even simpler. If you write code after the `Branch.new{}` wrapper, it will be executed after all branches within the wrapper have been completed. You don't need to manually ensure that all threads have finished, Branch does that for you.

```
Branch.new do
  branch { sleep 10 }
  branch { sleep 5 }

  # This will be printed immediately
  puts "All threads started!"
end

# This will be printed after 10 seconds (the duration of the slowest branch).
puts "All threads finished!"
```

Sequential `Branch.new{}` wrappers will be executed sequentially.

### Source

```
# (c) lolmaus (Andrey Mikhaylov), 2014
# MIT license http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/

class Branch
  def initialize(mutexes = 0, &block)
    @threads = []
    @mutexes = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Mutex.new }

    # Executing the passed block within the context
    # of this class' instance.
    instance_eval &block

    # Waiting for all threads to finish
    @threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
  end

  # This method will be available within a block
  # passed to `Branch.new`.
  def branch(delay = false, &block)

    # Starting a new thread 
    @threads << Thread.new do

      # Implementing the timeout functionality
      sleep delay if delay.is_a? Numeric

      # Executing the block passed to `branch`,
      # providing mutexes into the block.
      block.call @mutexes
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Supplying a new mutex per branch adds nothing. They might as well not be there. The rest of it is pretty neat.

Comment: D'oh, of course, it should be a `@mutex` defined in initialization. Will fix.

Comment: If you want to abstract away mutexes, then rather than do it in the branch class, i would do it in the thread safe data it is supposed to protect.

Comment: Suppose you have multiple threads accessing 2 completely independent arrays. With one mutex, accessing one will block the other, whereas having one mutex per array allows as much concurrency as you can afford whilst maintaining safety.

Comment: I've updated the code to allow multiple mutexes. Please see the source and the second example. Note how you don't have to instantiate each mutex manually, they are created lazily when you use them. What do you think?

Comment: It is a neat trick, but ultimately not the Branch classes concern so it breaks SRP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58407/discussion-between-lolmaus-andrey-mikhaylov-and-asquirrel).

Answer (score 3):

Like people said, it's not possible to achieve what you want without using Threads or a library that abstracts their functionality. But, if it's just the `setTimeout` functionality you want, then the implementation is actually very small.

Here's my attempt at emulating Javascript's `setTimeout` in ruby:

```
require 'thread'
require 'set'

module Timeout
  @timeouts = Set[]
  @exiting = false

  @exitm = Mutex.new
  @mutex = Mutex.new

  at_exit { wait_for_timeouts }

  def self.set(delay, &blk)
    thrd = Thread.start do
      sleep delay
      blk.call
      @exitm.synchronize do
        unless @exiting
          @mutex.synchronize { @timeouts.delete thrd }
        end
      end
    end

    @mutex.synchronize { @timeouts << thrd }
  end

  def self.wait_for_timeouts
    @exitm.synchronize { @exiting = true }
    @timeouts.each(&:join)
    @exitm.synchronize { @exiting = false }
  end
end
```

Here's how to use it:

```
$results = []
$rounds = 5

mutex = Mutex.new
def callback(n, mutex)
  -> {
    sleep rand(1..5)

    mutex.synchronize {
      $results << n
      puts "Fin: #{$results}" if $results.size == $rounds
    }
  }
end

1.upto($rounds) { |i| Timeout.set(0, &callback(i, mutex)) }

puts "Hello"
```

This outputs:

```
Hello
Fin: [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```

As you can see, the way you use it is essentially the same, the only thing I've changed is I've added a mutex to prevent race conditions on the results array.

#### Aside: Why we need the mutex in the usage example

Even if javascript is only running on a single core, that does not prevent race conditions due to atomicity of operations. Pushing to an array is not an atomic operation, so more than one instruction is executed.

- Suppose it is two instructions, putting the element at the end, and incrementing the size. (`SET`, `INC`).
- Consider all the ways two pushes can be interleaved (taking symmetry into account):

  - `SET1 INC1 SET2 INC2`
  - `SET1 SET2 INC1 INC2`
- The first one is what we want, but the second one results in the second append overwriting the first.

Comment: Can this be refactored in such a manner that `$mutex` is not required to be defined on the outer level but is rather passed as an argument to the callback? This might be a bad idea, not sure.

Comment: Yep, it can. I've edited the answer to reflect that. I would avoid the globals in general when using this in practise.

Comment: You still require user to define a mutex. Can it be defined automatically within the `Timeout` module?

Comment: No, it cannot. Javascript does not do this for you either. If you wrote the same code in javascript, using `setTimeout` and a javascript `Array` you would not be able to guarantee thread safety without a mutex.

Comment: (The reason why it is not possible is because `Timeout` doesn't know what's happening in the callback, and there is not "general rule" for mutexes that will apply to all cases).

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, at least in browser. I suppose that on the low level callbacks are broken down into instructions. Those instructions run interleaved to imitate parallel execution (this is what Ruby should also do when you spawn more threads than there are CPU cores). But in JS those interlaced instructions always run sequentially, so there are no race conditions or a need to synchronization.

Comment: I think you're wrong concerning JS: it is not prone to race conditions caused by the atomicity of operations. Many sources over the web say so. But this is offtopic. Back to Ruby. I've wrapped my head around your solution and came up with my own solution. It is similar to yours, but instead of requiring user to create a mutex manually, it requires to wrap the code with `Branch.new{...}`. The source is also much simpler than yours. Please check out my answer below.